# Custom Number Formatter in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode6

I wanted to make a custom NumberFormatter for my App so that I have some additional properties such as "lengthSymbol".
But every time I want to add an property this works:

```
let lengthSymbol:String = "ft"
```

But actually I want to set the property later so that I have

```
let lengthSymbol:String
```

And I thought I could do later:

```
init(symbol:String) {
    lengthSymbol = symbol
}
```

But I get the error that I have to implement this:

```
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

That's my first question: What actually is this?

And I also have to do something in the "init" function - I get the error "Super.init isn't called before returning to initializer"
What do I have to do now?

Would be great if someone could help me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a property observer function:

```
var lengthSymbol: String {
    didSet {
        // your initialization stuff here
    }
}
```

See the appropriate chapter in [The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-XID_368)

Comment: Ok thanks I'll read through this later but could you tell me what that "super.init" is and the "required init" with a NSCoder?

Comment: Remove the init functions from your code and try the property observer I described in my answer. If your property variable is simply a String you don't need to override the init functions.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is a variable, not a constant.

```
var lengthSymbol : String?
```

It should be optional because it most likely should work no matter if it is set or not.

Comment: Ok thank you that works - but what do I have to if I want to set the variable when initializing the class? When I add "init(symbol:String) {...}" I always need the "required init" - and I really don't know what that is .. you know I'm not really familiar with swift yet

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement the `NSCoding` protocol on an `NSFormatter` if the formatter instance lives in a Nib file.  The [Archiving guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Archiving.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000047i) can tell you specifically about this, but long story short, you just have to implement the scaffold method and add a method that deserializes the `lengthSymbol` variable and calls super.init in the tail.

```
init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
     lengthSymbol = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("MyFormatter_LengthKey")

     return super.init(coder:aDecoder)
}
```

You'll also have to implement `encodeWithCoder` but it's pretty straightforward.